# Email sent from apex class is not recevied

Tags: email

I have a visualforce page which does some calculations and sends email to the concerned people.

The problem I am facing is - the email is sent from the apex class perfectly without any errors or limits exceeded but it is not received at the users end.

I checked the spams for the email accounts and the email was not there.

I also do not see any errors happening at apex side. To test it further, I removed the email functionality from the logic and just did a dummy email test run, but it did not work either

```
private static void testEmail() {
    try {
        List<String> emailAddressList = new List<String>();
        emailAddressList.add('someemail@email.com'); -- (I put my personal email here)
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailsList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(emailAddressList);
        mail.setSubject('subject for this email');
        mail.setHtmlBody('blab blah blah.....');
        mailsList.add(mail);
        List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> emailResultList = Messaging.sendEmail(mailsList);
        System.debug('-------------------------------------- Email sent status : ' + emailResultList[0].isSuccess());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('---------------- Error occurred in testEmail() : ' + e.getStackTraceString());
    }
}
```

When this method is called, the email sent status is true.

[image: debug screenshot]

This is a simple email and it did not work. I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you post your visualforce page

Comment: It an empty page with a controller (I have not written any vf code yet). The constructor calls this testEmail method.

Comment: does ur vf page has apex:form tags in it

Comment: No the page is empty, there is nothing in there. I just refresh the page and the constructor calls that method.

Comment: <apex:page controller="sendEmail">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Send an Email to Contact">
        <apex:form><br/><br/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}"/> 
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>

Comment: try to call sendemail method from commandbutton..use above code

Comment: Ok so it worked when I sent it from a command button. But I want it to be sent automatically. Any idea?

Comment: Apex Message.sendEmail must be only used in an action with a form submit.  It will not work with an AJAX call.

Comment: Then what do I do if I want to send an email from a trigger or non-form related action?

Comment: u can send it from trigger but not via ajax call

Comment: But I was not using a ajax call, I was calling the method from a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171487&language=en_US

Looks like you can't send email from a constructor directly. In that knowledge article is says if you want to do something on page load to put it in a method in a controller and set it to the 'action=""' on your vf page tag

Comment: Wow, did not knew that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too simple but ensure that you have email delivery turned on for your org:

1: go to the setup tab
2: click on Email Administration
3: click on Deliverability
4: ensure the "Access to Send Email" section has "All Emails" selected in the Access Level dropdown list. [image]

Comment: It was already set to All email. The weird thing is, I have another email functionality which works perfectly fine. But this little method is not working.

Comment: Thanks, I see you found an answer though (Or it appears as such). I'm not sure I follow though, the solution mentions not being able to send it from a constructor, but your code doesn't look like it's in a constructor...I don't have enough rep to comment on the solution though :(

Comment: Even though my code was not in constructor it was called from a constructor. The testEmail method was called from constructor. So as it turns out, email cannot be sent from a constructor (which makes sense given how many times a page can be refreshed). More helpful link  - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171487&language=en_US